# How to find the largest value in a column of strings in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of JIRA task identifier in a column in Excel (a number pre-pended with a string identifier) and I want to find the highest one so I can check to see if there are any new items I need to add.

|  |
| --- |
| PHNX-298 |
| PHNX-317 |
| PHNX-296 |
| PHNX-310 |
| PHNX-175 |
| PHNX-281 |
| PHNX-307 |
| PHNX-67 |

How can I find the identifier with the largest number (in this case PHNX-317) using a single excel expression (no use of an intermediate column).
How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the strings to pull only the number and find the max then find that number in the column with INDEX/MATCH.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&MAX(--MID(A1:A8,6,3)),A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, what does the "--" ahead of the MID do?

Comment: @markshancock it is a double unary.  It basically multiplies the value which is a string that the MID returns by -1 * -1.  It is a shortcut to turn a number stored as a string to a true number.  Without it the "numbers" would remain a string and the MAX would ignore them and return 0.

Comment: How can I make it work with empty cells so it is extensible (not having to do "A1:A8")?

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&MAX(--MID(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),6,3)),A:A,0))`  Now it will find the last cell with data in column A and set that as the end.